# Why opencv video reading fps is not same with video encrypted fps?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, frame-rate

In OpenCV with Python, when the fps of the webcam and a video file in the directory are same, why does the video file play in fast forward whereas the webcam continues to show the frames at a normal rate? What role does the cv2.waitKey() function play here

Answer (score 2):

The fps of a video file means how it was encrypted, how many frames contain within a second as the name reveals. For example, if extracted 1 second of this video will produce only that number of frames (images).

The corresponding fps of the web camera means how many frames that camera can capture in a second. If saved to a video file that would mean how many frames are contained within each 1-second span.

There is a third (probably hidden to you) concept here though. How fast the opencv can read a video file. Normally, and for typical resolutions on a modern computer this fps is larger than the actual video. So, your computer seem to playback the video in fast forward mode because it reads (and displays) frames in a faster pace than the video file's fps.

Theoretically, you can calculate the delay you should import to the video playback to force it to displayed with normal pace. I am not sure how easily you can accomplish that (in a scientific way and not trial and error mode).

Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Right, got it. Thank you!

Comment: @tery1315 if an answer covers you can mark it as the solution to the problem to let others know that this question has been solved/answered etc.